# R: Update a mysql table with data frame

Tags: r, dbi, rmysql, dbplyr

I have a MariaDB and I want to update a table with a local R data frame. As an example, I have a table with these column names:

`id,foo,bar`

`id` is the primary key on the data base table.

Is there a function with which I can easily update the remote data base with my local data frame? Ideally, I am looking for something like this:

`update_table(con, remote_table_name, local_data_frame, primary_key="id")`

I am aware that I could write the SQL statement like this into a string and then execute it with `DBI::dbSendStatement(con, query)`:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, foo, bar)
VALUES (1, 'a1', 'b1'),
(2, 'a2', 'b2'),
(3, 'a3', 'b3'),
(4, 'a4', 'b4'),
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=VALUES(id),
foo=VALUES(foo),
bar=VALUES(bar)
```

But I would be surprised if there is not an out-of-the-box solution for this seemingly simple operation. Does anybody have an idea if such a function is embedded in a package?

Comment: The [`dbx`](https://github.com/ankane/dbx) package supports upserts, not sure of its status with mariadb. Your query is only bespoke because you hand-jam the data; the way I do it is to `dbWriteTable` the data to be updated into a temp table on the database, then use the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE ...` query from the temp table to the table to be updated. It's far more generalizable that way, and benefits from other existing `DBI` functions.

Comment: The `dbx` package does exactly what I needed. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dbx` package has a function which does exactly what I needed:

```
dbxUpdate(db, table, records, where_cols=c("id"))
```

It does work with MariaDB.

Answer (score 1):

Now, the `dbplyr` package also has [`rows_update()`](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/rows-db.html)

```r
rows_update(table, records, by = "id", copy = TRUE)
```